# Why does the same code run in different runtime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

```
def insertsort(iterable) :
    global start_time
    start_time = time.time()
    for current in range(1,len(iterable)) : # iterable[0] is consdiered as resorted in the beginning
        current_value = iterable[current] # saving current value
        compare = current
        while 0 < compare and iterable[compare-1] > current_value : # finding out where to put the sorted current value
            iterable[compare] = iterable[compare-1] # this line in the while loop moves the elements not sorted
            compare -= 1 

        iterable[compare] = current_value # put current value into the right place that the while loop found out

    calruntime()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    
    return(iterable)

runtime={}
def calruntime() :
    global runtime
    runtime.update({time.asctime() : time.time() - start_time})


for n in range(25) : # 25 tests
    data = [i for i in range(5000,0,-1)] # number of sample: 5000
    insertsort(data)
```

I measured the runtime of this code, and I found that each runtime differs although they all are the same with the same input.(didn't make any randomization)

When I made a log of it, it was like the following.

```
Sun Aug  2 10:26:24 2020 : 4.42353892326355
Sun Aug  2 10:26:28 2020 : 4.32453989982605
Sun Aug  2 10:26:32 2020 : 4.24298882484436
Sun Aug  2 10:26:37 2020 : 4.3115057945251465
Sun Aug  2 10:26:41 2020 : 4.226868152618408
Sun Aug  2 10:26:45 2020 : 4.148167371749878
Sun Aug  2 10:26:49 2020 : 4.231259107589722
Sun Aug  2 10:26:54 2020 : 4.3146984577178955
Sun Aug  2 10:26:58 2020 : 4.167114019393921
Sun Aug  2 10:27:02 2020 : 4.247375965118408

Average : 4.263805651664734
```

They differ from about 4.14 to 4.42 with an average of 4.26.

The differing range is about 6% of the average runtime, which I consider significant.

I want to know why this difference occurs since I ran the same code with the same input and got different runtimes.

I assume this is because the computer assigns the data in different addresses each time in spite of the same code.

I'd appreciate your answers in advance :D

Comment: This seems like normal random variation to me

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see no random variation in my code. Which random variation do you mean exactly?

Comment: The normal variation in the time it takes for identical code to execute. I assume you are executing this code on an *operating system*, correct? Unless it's a real-time OS you shouldn't expect the same time. Presumably, it's not the *only process running, correct?*

Comment: Is there a meal that you make regularly? Or some other semi-consistent process, e.g. changing the oil in your car, making your bed, brushing your teeth, walking your dog,... Does it always take the _exact same_ amount of time, to the second, even to the thousandth of a second? Why would there be any variation in that process? You do it all the time, right? It should be pretty consistent...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say for sure, but I think it would be due to some other processes also being executed at the same time. I do know that, while the data would be assigned a different address each time, the time to access that data should be constant and equivalent for each different address, so the variation in time must be coming from some other source.

Answer (score 0):

Good benchmarking is HARD on current systems. Not only does the OS and drivers  and services and other apps interact with interval timing but we have to consider timer resolution and latency. You probably think runtime is deterministic: as you have just demonstrated, it is not very. At least when viewed from a program. It is possible to force deterministic behavior but not easily. Telling you how would involve books worth of info. Please just accept +- 6% as a reasonable measure. If you must, start testing based on number of digits of accuracy desired (NOT precision). To get to 3 9s, estimate thousands of tests, and a course in probability and statistics. The one cause of variation "address" is almost certainly not a significant cause! Just one sample possible source: assume system hooked to TCP-IP. packets randomly arrive, driver interrupts, sometimes discards packet or buffers. then your program resumes. Many many variations on this idea.